# how to count how many element changed its position in a list after sorting?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I want to print the count of numbers that have changed their position.
My code:

```
def mysort(arr):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)): 
        min_value = i
        for j in range(i, len(arr)): 
            if arr[j] < arr[min_value]:
                min_value = j
                count += 1
        
        temp = arr[i] 
        arr[i] = arr[min_value] 
        arr[min_value] = temp 
    
    return count 

my_list = [4,2,3,1,6,5]
print(mysort(my_list))
```

My code is returning `3` as output but it should return `4`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of elements with positions changed, why not try:

```
def count_change(old, new):
    # assume old and new have the same length
    count = 0
    for x,y in zip(old, new):
        if x != y:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Your code actually counts the number of value swap

Comment: Or `sum(x != y for (x, y) in zip(old, new))`

Comment: Or `sum(map(operator.ne, old, new))`